# Move data from one table to another in the oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

how to move data from 3 tables to another in oracle?
select aid ,aname,aage into tTableD from tTableA ,tTableB,tTableC

[image]

Comment: Does that `select` return the data you want (seems unlikely since you're doing a three table Cartesian product)?  If so, just put an `insert into tableD` in front of it.  If not, help us help you.  Show us the data in the tables, the result you want, etc.  From looking at the image, I'd guess that you wanted to do a `union all` of the tables rather than joining them but that's a guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that all the ID values are distinct (or are not going into a unique column) then:

```sql
INSERT INTO tTableD ( aID, aName, aAge )
SELECT aID, aName, aAge FROM tTableA UNION ALL
SELECT aID, aName, aAge FROM tTableB UNION ALL
SELECT aID, aName, aAge FROM tTableC;
```

If they are not distinct and the `aID` column has a unique constraint then you will need to generate new ID values and assuming that you have a sequence named `tTableD__aID__seq`:

```sql
INSERT INTO tTableD ( aID, aName, aAge )
SELECT tTableD__aID__seq.NEXTVAL, aName, aAge
FROM (
  SELECT aName, aAge FROM tTableA UNION ALL
  SELECT aName, aAge FROM tTableB UNION ALL
  SELECT aName, aAge FROM tTableC
);
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=cef33bb5ad2877f50bccf3cb9fb10662)*